# GitHub Actions is not permitted to create or approve pull requests (createPullRequest)

Tags: github, github-actions

Since the 3rd of May this month, github added the setting `Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests` for creating pull requests in github actions, under `Settings > Actions > General`. However, it seems I cannot select this option for my repo, it is grayed out without any explanation why it is grayed out.

Whenever the "default permissions" setting is changed and saved, it is possible to select the `Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests`, but if it is saved it snaps back to the original grayed out version, unchecked.

I also tried giving the workflow file the pull-request permission like so:

```yaml
permissions:
   pull-requests: write
```

but that didn't work either. Is there something I am missing which prevents me from using pull requests within github actions?

[image: 'Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests' setting]
[image: Failing GitHub Actions PR creation]

Comment: Are you trying this on a personal account in a private repo?

Comment: I am trying this on a public repo in an organisation.

Comment: Are you an admin in your org?

Comment: Yes, I created the organisation. So it seems there is an organisational setting which you can toggle, but not per repo

Comment: sorry, correction, you can toggle the setting if the organisational setting has been toggled on, thanks for looking in the right direction!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you manage to solve it @Devxln ?

Answer (score 70):

You are probably using an organization, which means you must first enable this behavior on the organization level and then on the repository level

1. Go to https://github.com/organizations/YOUR_ORG/settings/actions and check `Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests`
2. Then go to https://github.com/YOUR_ORG/YOUR_REPO/settings/actions and check the box that previously was grayed out

Comment: Great, thank you! Seems step 2 wasn't required in my case, because it was already checked by the first step I guess.

Comment: 0. If you are using GitHub Enterprise, you need to check the box there also https://github.com/enterprises/YOUR_ENTERPRISE/settings/actions
Additionally it seems to enable it in the organization and repositories by default after enabling it in the enterprise.

Comment: A million thanks @aviggiano

Answer (score 1):

On top of Aviggiano's reply. In case you have an **Enterprise** level account, the settings to `Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests` have to be set at the **Enterprise** settings level and not at the Organization level.

`https://github.com/enterprises/<YOUR_ORG>/settings/actions`